# Advanced Custom Fields stay on page after being delted

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an issue with deleting my Advanced Custom Fields. 
When I delete them through the editor, they stay on the actual website.

I tried clearing all of the possible cache several times, however, that didn't help. I also tried to contact ACF support, they said its an issue in the code and they cannot help, bellow is the PHP code for the page.

This is code by a developer who worked previously on this project and has a very different way of working with ACF compared to me, so it's super confusing.

I have been struggling for a few days now, please helppppp. 
Thanks to everyone in advance.

```
 <?php /* Template Name: Gallery Template */ ?>

<?php get_header();
  global $post; ?>
<style type="text/css">
  .pdf-items img {
    min-height: 236px;
  }

  .hero {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/gallery09-min.jpg);
    background-position-y: center;
  }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
  .Schedules-section .pdf-items img {
    height: 478px !important;
  }

  .page-id-13293 .hero.ha-waypoint.parallax-section.parallax-background {
    margin-top: -70px;
  }

  .ui-tabs-nav {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .ui-tabs-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #D33E13;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #888888;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "ralewaymedium", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #F15523;
  }

  .tabs-inside .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active {
    background: rgba(0, 31, 91, 1);
  }

  .tabs-inside .ui-tabs-nav li {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 31, 91, 1);
  }

  .hidden-items {
    display: none;
  }

  .item-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "ralewayregular", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 100px;
  }

  .wrap {
    margin: 60px auto 70px;
  }

  .moreAction {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #D33E13;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #F15523;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .moreAction:hover,
  .moreAction:focus,
  .moreAction:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .item-title {
      min-height: 95px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mobile-view {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 625px) {
    .mobile-view {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .mobile-view .item-title {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  }

  #header-section {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 9);
  }
</style>
<?php 
$_SECTIONS[0]['name'] = 'PHOTOS';
$_SECTIONS[1]['name'] = 'VIDEOS';
$_SECTIONS[2]['name'] = 'DOWNLOADS';
$_SECTIONS[0]['items'][0] = array('sec_title' => 'PROJECTS' , 'image' => 'https://aalshipping.com/wp-content/gallery/aal-fremantle-discharging-railway-equipment-in-singapore-from-nansha-china/IMG-20180727-WA0004.jpg', 'title' => 'AAL Fremantle - Discharging Railway Equipment in Singapore from Nansha, China');
$_SECTIONS[0]['items'][1] = array('sec_title' => 'CARGO PROFILE' , 'image' => 'https://aalshipping.com/wp-content/gallery/aal-fremantle-discharging-railway-equipment-in-singapore-from-nansha-china/IMG-20180727-WA0004.jpg', 'title' => 'AAL Fremantle - Discharging Railway Equipment in Singapore from Nansha, China');
$_SECTIONS[0]['items'][2] = array('sec_title' => 'VESSELS' , 'image' => 'https://aalshipping.com/wp-content/gallery/aal-fremantle-discharging-railway-equipment-in-singapore-from-nansha-china/IMG-20180727-WA0004.jpg', 'title' => 'AAL Fremantle - Discharging Railway Equipment in Singapore from Nansha, China');
// $_SECTIONS[0]['items']['image'] = 'https://aalshipping.com/wp-content/gallery/aal-fremantle-discharging-railway-equipment-in-singapore-from-nansha-china/IMG-20180727-WA0004.jpg';
// $_SECTIONS[0]['items']['title'] = 'AAL Fremantle - Discharging Railway Equipment in Singapore from Nansha, China';
// $_SECTIONS[2]['items']['sec_title'] = 'VESSELS';
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
<section id="ut-hero" class="hero ha-waypoint parallax-section parallax-background fixed"
  data-animate-up="ha-header-hide" data-animate-down="ha-header-hide" style="background-position: 50% 16px;">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <!-- hero holder -->
    <div class="hero-holder grid-100 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100 ut-hero-style-2" style="opacity: 1;">
      <div class="hero-inner" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="hth">
          <h1 class="hero-title">Gallery</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="hdb"><span class="hero-description-bottom">
            <a data-id="1" class="hero-btn default tosection" href="javascript:void(0);">PHOTOS</a>
            <a data-id="2" class="hero-second-btn default tosection" href="javascript:void(0);">VIDEOS</a>
            <a data-id="3" class="hero-second-btn default tosection" href="javascript:void(0);">DOWNLOADS</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- close hero-holder -->
  </div>
  <div data-section="top" class="ut-scroll-up-waypoint"></div>
</section>
<div id="main-content" class="wrap ha-waypoint" data-animate-up="ha-header-hide" data-animate-down="ha-header-small">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php

    $_GALLERY_ITEMS = get_field("tabs_title", $post->ID);
      // if (isset($_GET['alex'])) {
      //    echo '<pre>';
      //    print_r($_GALLERY_ITEMS);
      //    echo '</pre>';
      // }
    $counter = 1;
    $tabs_counter = 1;
    foreach ($_GALLERY_ITEMS as $gitem) {

      $sections .= '<li><a class="active-tab-'.$tabs_counter.'" href="#tabs-'.$counter.'">'.$gitem['tabs_title'].'</a></li>';

        $section_html .= '<div id="tabs-'.$counter.'">';

        if (!empty($gitem['tabs_repeater_inside'])) {
          $counter_ = 1;
          $inscounter = 1;
          $section_html .= '<div id="tabss"  class="tabs-inside"><ul>';
          foreach ($gitem['tabs_repeater_inside'] as $insitems) {

            if ($insitems['section_header_titles'] != '') {
              $section_html .= '<li><a href="#tabss-'.$counter_.'">'.$insitems['section_header_titles'].'</a></li>';
            }
            $counter_ ++;
          }
          $section_html .= '</ul>';

          foreach ($gitem['tabs_repeater_inside'] as $insitems) {
            $more_btn = str_replace(' ', '_', $insitems['section_header_titles']);
            $itemsc = 1;
            if (!empty($insitems['section_titles'])) {
              $section_html .='<div id="tabss-'.$inscounter.'">';
              $section_html .= '<div class="'.$more_btn.'-section">';
              foreach ($insitems['section_titles'] as $item) {

                if ($item['item_video_url'] != '') {
                  $url = explode('watch?v=', $item['item_video_url']);
                  if ($itemsc <= 3) {
                    $section_html .= '<div class="'.($itemsc > 3 ? "hidden-items" : "").' '.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><!--a data-fancybox="'.$item['item_video_url'].'" href="'.$item['item_image']['url'].'"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$url[1].'/0.jpg"></a--><iframe width="340" height="276" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$url[1].'" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                      <span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span></div>';
                  } else {
                    if (isset($_GET['clear_cache'])) {
                      $items = '<div class="'.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><!--a data-fancybox="'.$item['item_video_url'].'" href="'.$item['item_image']['url'].'"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$url[1].'/0.jpg"></a--><iframe width="340" height="276" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$url[1].'" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span></div>';
                      $_ARRAY_IMAGES[$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc]['html'] = $items;
                    }
                  }
                } else if ($item['item_pdf'] != '') {
                if ($itemsc <= 3) {
                  $section_html .= '<div class="pdf-items '.($itemsc > 3 ? "hidden-items" : "").' '.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><a href="'.$item['item_pdf']['url'].'" title="'.$item['item_pdf']['title'].'"><img src="'.$item['item_image']['sizes']['galleryv2'].'" alt="'.$item['item_image']['title'].'"></a>
                  <span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span>
                  </div>';
                } else {
                  if (isset($_GET['clear_cache'])) {
                    $items = '<div class="pdf-items '.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><a href="'.$item['item_pdf']['url'].'" title="'.$item['item_pdf']['title'].'"><img src="'.$item['item_image']['sizes']['galleryv2'].'" alt="'.$item['item_image']['title'].'"></a>
                    <span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span>
                    </div>';
                    $_ARRAY_IMAGES[$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc]['html'] = $items;
                  }
                }

                } else {
                if ($itemsc <= 3) {
                $section_html .= '<div class="'.($itemsc > 3 ? "hidden-items" : "").' '.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><div class="image-holder">
                <a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="'.$item['item_image']['url'].'">
                  <img src="'.$item['item_image']['sizes']['galleryv2'].'">
                </a>
                </div><span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span></div><div class="hidden-items">';

                  for ($i=1; $i <= $item['total_image']; $i++) {
                    // $section_html .= '<a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"></a>';
                    $section_html .= '<a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"></a>';
                  }
                  $section_html .= '</div>';
                } else {
                  if (isset($_GET['clear_cache'])) {
                    $items = '<div class="'.$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc.' col-md-4 col-sm-6 mobile-view"><div class="image-holder">
                    <a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="'.$item['item_image']['url'].'">
                      <img src="'.$item['item_image']['sizes']['galleryv2'].'">
                    </a>
                    </div><span class="item-title">'.$item['item_title'].'</span></div><div class="hidden-items">';
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $item['total_image']; $i++) {
                      // $section_html .= '<a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"></a>';
                      $items .= '<a data-fancybox="'.$item['images_folder'].'" href="/wp-content/uploads/'.$item['images_folder'].'/image'.$i.'.jpg"></a>';
                    }
                    $items .= '</div>';
                      $_ARRAY_IMAGES[$more_btn.'-'.$itemsc]['html'] = $items;
                  }
                }


                }

                $itemsc ++;
              }
              $section_html .= '</div>';
              $section_html .= '<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <input type="hidden" class="'.$more_btn.'-total" value="'.($itemsc - 1).'">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="moreAction '.$more_btn.'" data-item="'.$more_btn.'-3">Load More</a></div>';
                $section_html .='</div>';
            }
            $inscounter ++;

          }

          $section_html .= '</div>';

          $counter ++;
        }
          $section_html .= '</div>';
      $counter ++;
      $tabs_counter ++;
    }
  if (isset($_GET['clear_cache'])) {
      $file = fopen('/home/australa/public_html/gallery.json','w');
      fwrite($file, json_encode($_ARRAY_IMAGES));
      fclose($file);
  }
?>
        <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
            <?php echo $sections; ?>
          </ul>
          <?php echo $section_html; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    jQuery(function () {
      jQuery("#tabs, #tabss").tabs();
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery(".moreAction").click(function () {
        var counter, array, split, i, total, x, images, start, images_clear;
        array = jQuery(this).attr('data-item');
        split = array.split("-");
        counter = +split[1] + 3;
        total = jQuery('.' + split[0] + '-total').val();
        start = (+split[1] + 1);
        if (total > counter) {
          jQuery(this).attr('data-item', '' + split[0] + '-' + counter + '');
        } else {
          jQuery(this).hide();
        }
        jQuery.getJSON("/gallery.json", function (json) {
          for (i = start; i <= counter; i++) {
            x = split[0] + '-' + i;
            if (json[x] != null) {
              images += json[x]['html'];
            }

          }
          images_clear = images.replace("undefined", "");
          jQuery('.' + split[0] + '-section').append(images_clear);
        });

      });
    });

    jQuery('.tosection').click(function () {
      var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
      jQuery('.active-tab-' + id).click();
      jQuery("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('#tabs').offset().top - 300
      }, 1200);
    });
  </script>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey, sounds like there are elements referencing  ACF fields hardcoded into your template which have to be deleted. A link to the site would be helpful to see what we're dealing with. Also, is this the entire contents of the PHP file? If not, plesae post the full thing. You're trying to remove the tabbed repeater fields right?

Comment: Hey @FalsePozitive , I updated the code with the entire PHP file, and here is the link to the page with the issue. The problem is, I deleted a few videos, one of which is AAL in Action – v05.2018 but they stay on the page anyways. aalshipping.com/gallery-v2